# Conditional expected value, joint distribution, independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

For $x_1,...,x_n\in N(a,1)$, i.i.d., is it correct that 
$$E\left(x_1 \,\Big\lvert\, \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}=M\right)=\int_ℝ \frac{xf_{x_1}(x)f_{x_2+\cdots+x_n}(Mn-x)}{f_{\frac {x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}}(M)}dx\,?$$

I'm doing an exercise in statistics and feeling a bit lost. After that I substitute Normal Distributions' pdf-s and try to solve the integral, but with no success.

Comment: No it is not correct.

Comment: @StubbornAtom why?

Comment: There should be a joint density of $(X_1,\frac1n\sum X_i)$ in the numerator.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is there a way to split it into a product of two densities the way i tried? the formula for joint densitiy for two variables that are dependant is complicated, but with independent it's just a product

Comment: Here distribution of $(X_1,\frac1n\sum X_i)$ is bivariate normal. In fact distribution of $X_1$ conditioned on $\frac1n\sum X_i$ is univariate normal. But none of these are required to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are i.i.d. (not necessarily normal), then by symmetry
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[x_1|x_1+\dots+x_n = nM] &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[x_i|x_1+\dots+x_n = nM]\\
&=\frac{1}{n} E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\middle|x_1+\dots+x_n = nM\right]\\
&= M
\end{align*}

Comment: can the integral approach give any results? is it wrong?

Comment: The integral approach should give the same result, and in the case of Gaussian you should be able to compute it.